# Difference between using malloc and initializer for array?

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, free, initializer

Why do I have to `free` an array created using malloc, but not one created using an initializer?

```
float* rgba = malloc(4 * sizeof(float));
free(rgba);
```

versus:

```
float rgba[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
free(rgba); // ERROR
```

What is happening under the hood here in the second one?

Comment: One is dynamically-allocated, the other isn't.

Comment: "Designated initializer"? Where exactly do you see a designated initializer in these declarations?

Comment: Oops, I typed that out initially in both the question body and title then changed it in the question body. I forgot to update the title.

Comment: Are you asking what's happening under the hook in some specific implementation? Because you haven't said what implementation you're using. Are you asking what happens typically? Or what's required to happen?

Comment: I think the question was answered sufficiently, but I'm using Objective-C (and c) on iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that `malloc` always allocates memory from the dynamic memory, while initializer places the data in either the static or the automatic memory, depending on the context where you define `rgba`:

- If your definition is outside any function, or if you add `static` to the definition, `rgba` is allocated in the static area, and gets either static or global visibility
- If you declaration is inside a function, then the memory is allocated in the automatic area (also known as "on the stack").

Since calls of `free` may be passed only pointers returned by a function from the `malloc` family (`malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc`) or other functions that return dynamic memory (e.g. `strdup`), calling `free` on non-malloc-ed pointer is undefined behavior.

Comment: Does this mean if `rgba` is created using an initializer, the memory will be freed automatically after it goes out of scope (suppose I defined it in a function, and it's not static, after the function is done, `rgba` will be freed automatically)?

Comment: @user3100783 Yes, the memory will be cleared automatically as soon as `rgba` is out of scope. That's the reason why it is not allowed to return pointers to such arrays from a function.

Comment: @user3100783 In both cases, `rgba` *itself* is freed automatically after it goes out of scope. The difference is that in one case `rgba` is a pointer and in the other it's an array. In the case where `rgba` is a pointer, something needs to free the array that it points to, and that array has no scope (other than the life of the program).

Comment: That's a good point @DavidSchwartz I didn't even think about the pointer being freed.

Answer (score 3):

**In the first case:**

there is allocation in the heap memory segment. Whatever allocated in the heap has to be de-allocated by the user. The compiler is not responsible for the automatic de-allocation.

**In the second case :**

The memory allocation takes place either in the stack or in the data segment depending on whether you allocate the array inside a function or globally!

If you allocate the array outside a function it gets allocated in the **data segment** section of memory.

if you allocate the array inside the function it gets allocated in the **stack.**

Whatever allocated in the stack or data segment automatically gets de-allocated. There is no need for explicit de-allocation from the user side.

Answer (score 0):

Because

```
float rgba[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
```

here array memory is allocated on stack. Compiler itself frees that memory when program goes out of the scope. If you free it, compiler will free it and it will case of double free.

In the first, you are allocating the memory to heap. User is responsible for freeing the heap memory allocated by the user. That is why `free` in first case will work.

Comment: The problem is not just a double free, it's freeing memory to something other than the allocator that allocated it, which is frequently catastrophic even if it's the only free.

Answer (score 0):

First case is dynamically allocated memory , where memory is allocated in **heap** section of memory. This means that the memory allocation is done at run-time, after compilation.

Second case is the normal, local variable creation, where memory is allocated during compile-time in the **stack** section of memory.

the free() function is used to de-allocate memory allocated during **run time only**, not *compile time*. Hence you are getting error.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there are no "designated initializers" in any of your examples. Your second example uses aggregate initializer syntax without any actual initializers in it being "designated".

Secondly, none of this has anything to do much with aggregate initializers. The primary difference resides on the left-hand side: `float* rgba` in the first case and `float rgba[]` in the second case.

In the second case you are actually declaring *an array*, and it is either a local or static array (depending on where that declaration resides). Local and static memory shall not be deallocated with `free`. It cannot be deallocated by you at all. You don't own local or static memory, which means that it is not your business to worry about its deallocation. Local and static objects have pre-determined lifetimes that follow pre-determined rules. They are created and destroyed automatically in full accordance with those rules.

In the first case you are not really declaring an array at all. You are declaring a *pointer* that points to a dynamically allocated memory block. You own all memory blocks you dynamically allocate, which means it is your responsibility to properly deallocate them.

Comment: Why do people bother to use dynamic memory for arrays? What are the pros and cons?

Comment: @user3100783: Dynamic memory is not just for arrays. The *primary* reason to use dynamic memory is to obtain manual control over the lifetime of the object. Dynamic memory is allocated at the moment *you* allocate it and disappears at the moment *you* deallocate it. Thus, you can create objects that live as long as you want them to live. None of this is possible with static or automatic objects. The latter kinds are created and destroyed automatically without you having any say in it.

Comment: @user3100783: Also, dynamic memory allocation allows you to "manufacture" objects in *run-time* quantities. Other kinds of memory can only create objects in *compile-time* quantities (variable-length arrays are exception from that rule). Finally, dynamic memory usually can accommodate huge objects, which are too large for other memory types.

Comment: @user3100783 In addition to AndreyT's points, sometimes your object simply does not fit on the stack, because it's too large. In cases like that you are also forced to use dynamic memory.